# circle image not working on Opera

Tags: css

I have an image and my css places it inside circle. The only problem is that it is not working on Opera browser. Any idea how to fix it?

my CSS:

```
.circular {
overflow: hidden;

width: 48px;
height: 48px;

border-radius: 550px;

box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 10, 2.8);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 10, 0, 2.8);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 10, 0, 2.8);

background-image:url('img/backg.png');


}
```

Comment: *it's now working* ...would be helpful you describe *what* isn't working. http://jsbin.com/osUSeqU/1/edit Probably some `-o-` vendor prefix for older Opera?

Comment: circle is created. Image placed above circle and still looks in square format, i thing overflow hidden is not working. looks like cannot crop image in circle format

Comment: works on Opera 11.64 the image is contained inside the overflow:h parent

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're running Opera 10.60 or higher, all those properties are supported.

### [Reference for box-shadow](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/cross-browser-box-shadows/)

### [Reference for rgba (and other CSS3 color properties)](http://caniuse.com/css3-colors)

So what that means is, if you ARE running the correct version, you need to post the rest of your code to diagnose underlying issues.

Comment: circle created but image cannot be placed inside circle. looks like overflow not working properly

Answer (score 0):

Yes Html5 and css3 is still now under work-in-progress.Most of the browser invoking the latest feature of the Html5 and css3 .So I will suggest you use this two lines of css code to get your desire result for your opera browser.

-o-border-radius: 50px;
-o-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);

keep remember some important prefix we have to use for creating css rule
-webkit- for chrome and may be safari
-moz-for firefox
-o-for opera
-ms-microsoft